# Change pic on clicking li - Simplify javascript code

Tags: javascript, html-lists

Hello im new in Javascript. I created this Pen https://codepen.io/aineias/pen/dybwxGv which works fine and does what i want.I would like to know if there is any way to simplify the js code, or this is the best approach.
Thank you for any advice.

```js
// Code below changes the background color of li on click

     $(document).ready(function(){
              $('ul li ').click(function(){
                 if($(this).hasClass('one')){
                  $('li ').removeClass("gradient2");
                $(this).addClass("gradient2");
                     $('li ').removeClass("gradient1");
                    $('li ').removeClass("gradient3");
                 }
                else if($(this).hasClass('two')){
                $('li ').removeClass("gradient1");
                $(this).addClass("gradient1");
                   $('li ').removeClass("gradient2");
                  $('li ').removeClass("gradient3");
            }else{
                  $('li ').removeClass("gradient1");
             $(this).addClass("gradient3");
                $('li ').removeClass("gradient2");
            } });  });
//this one changes pictures based on the li choice 
            $('.list li').click(function(){
            var value=$(this).attr('data-src');
            $('.image-holder img').attr("src",value);  
            });
```

Comment: the format could be improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me. I might just beautify it a bit and try to get rid of a few lines

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('ul li ').click(function(){
    const self = $(this);
  
    if(self.hasClass('one')){
      $('li ').removeClass("gradient1 gradient2 gradient3");
      self.addClass("gradient2");
     }
    else if(self.hasClass('two')){
      $('li ').removeClass("gradient1 gradient2 gradient3");
      self.addClass("gradient1");
    }else{
      $('li ').removeClass("gradient1 gradient2");
      self.addClass("gradient3");
    }
});
  
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks way more cleaner.

Comment: Welcome! If the answer helped,  you can give an upvote to my answer :). Good day !!

Comment: Sorry im new here, tried to upvote but doesn't let me so i ticked your answer. Thanks and Have a nice day.

Comment: No worries!! :)